# ActiveRecord polymorphic association: making ID long instead of integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

With this as the seemingly only way to define a polymorphic association:

```
t.references :poly_column, :polymorphic => true
```

How can I make the resulting `poly_column_id` use `long` type instead of `integer` (default)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `change_column` after creating your table, to explicitly use whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Our first question should be, what does `t.references :poly_column, :polymorphic => true` actually do? Based on the example in the guide, we might expect it to be a shortcut for `t.integer :imageable_id` and `t.string  :imageable_type`, which we can also confirm in the [RailsAPI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference). So instead, just define them yourself:

```
t.long :poly_column_id
t.string :poly_column_type
```